# Exception when trying to use an existing instance of HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

> Update- The below issue was solved by setting the proxy for
>   HttpClientHandler. But I still wonder how the first request succeeded
>   without setting the proxy ever? Why would only subsequent
>   requests(after the first request) would fail because of proxy?

I have a simple class to reuse a single instance of "HttpClient" across different requests. The issue I am facing is that only the first call succeeds, while all the subsequent call fails with a SocketException.

```
public class MyHttpClient
 {
    private static readonly HttpClient client;
    static MyHttpClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://x.com");
    }
    public async Task<string> GetSecurityToken(LoginData data)
    {
        var reqMsg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        var reqContent = new StringContent(reqMsg, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response= await client.PostAsync("/api/v1/security/token", reqContent)
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result
    }
 }


// The above class is consumed as

        var client = new MyHttpClient();
        var login = new LoginData("abc@gmail.com", "xxxx");
        var result = await client.GetSecurityToken(login); // this call succeeds !
        var result1 = await client.GetSecurityToken(login); // this call fails with an exception, but why?
```

> The exception I get in second call is - SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Perhaps because the server *did* timeout? Have you tried using Fiddler or another debugging proxy to see what's actually going on, whether the request went to the server and whether the server responded?

Comment: Why is `PostAsync` not awaited?

Comment: That was a typo, PostAsync is awaited and I still get the same issue

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The server gives a response back in first call, using postman I can send successive calls and it does not time out.

Comment: Postman isn't a debugging proxy. You don't know what's going on in the second call. Use Fiddler to actually see what's going on. HttpClient doesn't use a *single* socket so what's going on?

Comment: Perhaps you're making multiple concurrent calls? Perhaps you need to relax the 2 connections per domain limit? Perhaps another `await` is missing, flooding the server with calls? You won't see any of these with Postman. On the other hand, with Fiddler you'll see the connections as they're sent, whether the server responded or not, what the contents of the response were

Comment: When using fiddler the code runs perfectly fine, however when I close fiddler the code starts giving exception. Has this something to do with my corporate proxy ?